# What is std::views::counted?

Tags: c++, std, c++20, std-ranges

On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges, **std::views::counted** is listed in the **range adaptors** section. However, it is not tagged as range adaptor object.

I guess that why I can't write using the pipe operator like:

```
std::vector<size_t> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto view = vec | std::ranges::counted(... ; // does not compile
```

My questions are:

- what is a **std::ranges::counted?** Why is it listed in the range adaptor section?
- what are the use cases? what are the advantages over using **take** and **drop**?

Comment: "*what is a std::ranges::counted?*" Nothing. There is a `std::ranges::views::counted`.

Comment: [Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G8Ysv8sPG)

Answer (score 7):

Cppreference is following the organization of the C++20 standard. And it puts `views::counted` into [the "Range Adaptors" section](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/range.adaptors). Despite the fact that the standard says:

> These adaptors can be chained to create pipelines of range transformations that evaluate lazily as the resulting view is iterated.

This is not true of the *behavior* of `views::counted`. Indeed, most of the other elements in that section say that their customization points "denotes a [range adaptor object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/range.adaptors#range.adaptor.object)" (which describes the piping functionality), but [`views::counted` does not](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/range.counted).

It's unclear why they put it in that section, but it is a useful type in-and-of itself. It's really just an efficient way of saying `subrange(it, it + n)`. It is efficient in that it doesn't actually increment the iterator by `n`.

The advantage it has over `take_view` is that `take_view` operates on a range, while all `counted` needs is an iterator. The main difference is that `counted` *assumes* that there are `n` valid iterator positions (and will give UB if that is not the case), while `take_view` does not. `take_view` will give you *up to* `n` objects, but if the range is shorter than that (as defined by the sentinel), it doesn't try to iterate past the end of the range.

Answer (score 2):

`views::counted` is similar to `views::take`. However, the former accepts an iterator instead of a range.

One of the benefits of `views::counted` over `views::take` is that it allows us to construct a *sized* input/output range when we already know its size:

```
auto ints = views::istream<int>(std::cin);

auto counted = views::counted(ints.begin(), 4);
auto take    = views::take(ints, 4);

static_assert(ranges::sized_range<decltype(counted)>); // ok
static_assert(ranges::sized_range<decltype(take)>);    // failed
```

Unlike `views::take`, since we omit the sentinel information, we must ensure that the iterator is still valid after incrementing `n` times, while the former is guaranteed to always return a valid range.

Comment: Note that `take` does return a sized range if the given range is sized.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_counted)

> A counted view presents a view of the elements of the counted range [i, n) for some iterator i and non-negative integer n.
>
> A counted range [i, n) is the n elements starting with the element pointed to by i and up to but not including the element, if any, pointed to by the result of n applications of ++i.

So essentially it returns a slice given a starting iterator and a number of elements to include after that iterator. The example shown in the docs is

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    const int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    for(int i : std::views::counted(a, 3))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    const auto il = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (int i : std::views::counted(il.begin() + 1, 3))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

Comparing the specific functions you listed, here are their summaries:

- `std::ranges::views::take`: a view consisting of (up to) the first N elements of another view
- `std::ranges::views::drop`: a view consisting of elements of another view, skipping (up to) the first N elements
- `std::ranges::views::counted`: creates a subrange from an iterator and a count, always containing exactly N elements